# How to solve 'tee: Too many open files' when trying to redirect output to multiple files

Tags: curl, xargs, tee

I need to download hundreds of `json` files from a list of urls stored in a `csv`.
As it would be impossible to do so manually, I wrote a short bash script to read the urls one by one using Python and pass them to `curl` to download.
In addition, with the aid of `tee`, the script saves the downloaded data in files naming each one with a standard code. The code is stored in the same `csv` and the files are stored in a separate folder named 'Data':

```
output_dir=Data
python pass_urls_to_std_out.py | xargs curl -k | tee $output_dir/$(python pass_cd_to_std_out.py) > /dev/null
```

`pass_urls_to_std_out.py` is just a short Python script which reads the urls and passes them one by one to the standard output.

`pass_cd_to_std_out.py` is an analogous script which just reads the codes one by one.

`> /dev/null` is used just to avoid `tee` printing all the output of `curl` on screen.

Unfortunately, the script works fine for small sets of files, but when the number of files I'm trying to download increases, I get this error messages:

```
tee: 4208005.json: Too many open files
tee: 4110607.json: Too many open files
tee: 4304903.json: Too many open files
tee: 4217303.json: Too many open files
tee: 4212809.json: Too many open files
tee: 4214003.json: Too many open files
tee: 4208302.json: Too many open files
tee: 4203501.json: Too many open files
....
```

Is there a way to sequentially redirect output to one file at a time (or 10, 20 at a time), withtou tee trying to open all files at once?

[Edit] As [Kamil Maciorowski](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/108618/kamil-maciorowski) correctly pointed out, as I wrote it, instead of the output of `pass_cd_to_std_out.py` being passed one by one as arguments of `tee`, it's expanded and passed as multiple arguments all at once.

I rewrote the script as a for cycle:

```
#!/bin/bash

output_dir=Data

for url in $(eval python pass_urls_to_std_out.py); do
        curl -k $url > $output_dir/$(python pass_cd_to_std_out.py)
done
```

Unfortunately, `$output_dir` is evaluated only once and thus the output looks like:

```
Data/1200401.json
4205407.json
4106902.json
2304400.json
3304557.json
3205309.json
1600303.json
1400100.json
```

Comment: In many shells `$output_dir/$(python pass_cd_to_std_out.py)` will expand to multiple arguments. Problems: (1) [globbing](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/108618). (2) `Data/` will be prepended to the first one only. (3) Regardless of the number of arguments, there is exactly one `tee`, so it will try to save *identical data* to all destinations. Is this what you want? // All this makes me suspect "the script works fine for small sets of files" is not really true, unless the cardinality of  each of your "small sets" is one.

Comment: Thank you Kamil for your advice. My mistake stems from the fact that I tend to always think in a Pythonic way and write one liners as much as possible instead of for cycles. As you correctly pointed out, as I wrote it, instead of the output of pass_cd_to_std_out.py being passed one by one as arguments of tee, it's expanded and passed as multiple arguments. I rewrote the script as a for cycle, but the problem you pointed out as (2) still stands

Comment: Edit: it looks like the for loop is NOT the correct way to go and the output_dir variable is always gonna be evaluated once in a for loop (see: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001). Still can't understand why this is the case

Comment: Can't you just get all the URLs in a single invocation of `curl` and use `--output-dir=Data` with `-O` to save all the output in files in the `Data` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that, if instead of piping everything on the fly I save every step to file instead, it somehow works:

1. Check if directory `Data` exists, or otherwise create directory `Data`:

   ```
   download_dir=Data

   if [ ! -d $download_dir ]; then
     mkdir $download_dir
   fi
   ```
2. Create a file with all the URLs:

   ```
   python pass_urls_to_std_out.py >> urls.txt
   ```
3. Create a file with all the filenames:

   ```
   python pass_cd_to_std_out.py >> file_names.txt
   ```
4. Read each file line by line and recursively download data from url and save to filename:

   ```
   paste urls.txt file_names.txt | while IFS= read -r url file_name; 
     do curl -k --output-dir=Data $url > $file_name; 
   done
   ```

I added the `--output-dir` option
thanks to [Kusalananda's](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/116858/kusalananda) [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/726562/how-to-solve-tee-too-many-open-files-when-trying-to-redirect-output-to-multip/726740#comment1377665_726562) as well.